# isotope default height size cuts content

Tags: css, height

i have a page with a isotope container built into it http://www.nationalpaymentcard.com/products

Now on somebrowsers ive noticed it works fine but sometimes i get this issue
[image: img]

Here is my js code for the isotope

```
//Isotope sorting
 var $container = $('.projects');

 $('.projects').isotope({
 layoutMode : 'straightDown',
  filter: '.sort_category1',
  resizesContainer: true,
  resizable: true,    
 });
```

Not sure why im getting that issue, been digging through it with inspect element but cant seem to get why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Viewing that page in Safari 5.1.9 the "Send Message!" and "Clear Form" buttons don't even show up. It would be helpful if you told us what browsers specifically are having what issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The send buttons are having issues because you have `overflow:hidden;` for div.projects.

Use the inspector to select that `div` and set `overflow:visible;` and they show up.
I assume this will fix both problems but I wasn't able to get the cut-off result you posted.

If you need help setting overflow to visible just ask. I don't use isotope so I'm not sure if there's an option but it can easily be done with a stylesheet. You may need to use JS or jQuery below your initial script though if isotope is setting it to hidden when it runs. Still no big deal.

Comment: yeah for some reason that element gets spit into the code, i think it has something to do with the js file

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you tried using `overflow:visible;` yet? You can edit the JS file to do whatever you want it too. Or you can just use some inline JS to change it.

Comment: i actually tried your suggestion, but it just appears behind the footer now

Comment: sorry it appears overlapping* the footer

Comment: What browser are you using? Like I said you NEED to give more information.

Comment: What browsers were having what issues? What version of said browsers and on what OS? I can't recreate your problem on my iMac at work running 10.6.8 with Safari 5.1.9 or Firefox 21. Here is what I see, looks great. http://i43.tinypic.com/547tdt.png. Here is Firefox http://oi42.tinypic.com/dw2d5j.jpg. Clear your caches and try again.

Comment: hmm must be safari 5.1.8 then

Comment: I'm trying to help you but you're making it ridiculously hard. I can't read your mind. Either give me and the rest of us on Stack some useful information to work with or fix it yourself. Nobody is this difficult to get information from.

Comment: are you ok? I said safari 5.1.8. what else do you need? you think the OSX version makes a diff - no. then what else? you wanna know what my wall paper is? wanna know what my favorite color is? What more must i provide you so you can do your "job" here?

Comment: The OS version does in fact matter. What an arrogant thing to say. This was the simplest question I've ever tried to answer, I can't believe it even needed asked. Most would have simply said you should learn some basic CSS rules with Google instead of asking. Be grateful I even helped you.

Comment: im so grateful, im sending you a pack of virgins and a fruit basket for your all powerful knowledge.

Comment: oh and for the record i switched it back to hidden, cause that visible tip wasent working..... so yeah sites good, was always good- thanks for hanging out

Comment: I love packs of virgins. Thanks. So you asked for help on something that "was always good?" Whatever man, have a good one.